# ASP.NET MVC architecture service layers etc where can HttpContext aware logic go?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, architecture

I have yet another ASP.NET MVC architecture question, I'm slowly getting there and piecing bits together but there is still a few missing links I'm trying to resolve. My current project structure is below, and I'm happy with that (although any constructive comments would be great), I'm not using IoC/DI yet but will be at somepoint, just bigger fish to fry at the moment!!.

My question is I have domain level business logic in the AppName.Core.Services namespace which is great, but I have some logic which requires to interact with HttpContext which checks for things in the Application cache etc. A really simple example is some code like this:

```
public int? GetCurrentClientId()
{
    int clientId = null;

    if (HttpContext.Current.Application["ClientId"] != null)
    {
        // Use value from application cache if one exists
        clientId = (int)HttpContext.Current.Application["ClientId"];
    }
    else
    {
        // Lookup using host name of site we are browsing
        string hostName = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostName.ToLower();
        UnitOfWork _unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();
        Client client = _unitOfWork.ClientRepository.GetSingle(x => x.HostName.ToLower() == hostName || x.LocalHostNames.ToLower().Contains(hostName));
        if (client != null) clientId = client.Id;
    }
    return clientId;
}
```

Now I can't stick all that in AppName.Core.Services as its HttpContext aware, so I'm breaking it down to the following code which can sit in the AppName.Core.Services but what I'm not sure about is where my logic goes which interacts with HttpContext etc to call this if required. I don't want it in my controllers, but I'm now wondering the best place for it, what namespace and conventions etc.

```
public int? GetClientIdFromHostName(string hostName)
{
    UnitOfWork _unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();
    Client client = _unitOfWork.ClientRepository.GetSingle(x => x.HostName.ToLower() == hostName || x.LocalHostNames.ToLower().Contains(hostName));
    if (client != null) return client.Id;
    else return null;
}
```

My previous research into this subject, and a prior question I asked here, pointed me towards accessing all my services from the controller... but if I can't have HttpContext based logic in my services where can it go??

[ASP.NET MVC - Service layer, single or many services in each controller action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905992/asp-net-mvc-service-layer-single-or-many-services-in-each-controller-action)

Project Structure:

```
AppName.Core (for all my domain objects, DAL, domain services etc... independant and not aware of web specifics HttpContext etc)
> Data
> Data > DataContext.cs
> Data > UnitOfWork.cs
> Entities
> Entities > User.cs
> Entities > Client.cs etc etc
> Migrations
> Migrations > (all the EF code first migrations bits)
> Repository
> Repository > UserRepository.cs
> Repository > ClientRepository.cs
> Repository > GenericRepository.cs etc etc
> Services
> Services > ClientService.cs etc etc

AppName.Web (for all my compiled HttpContext aware code, ViewModels etc... references AppName.Core only)
> AutoMapper
> AutoMapper > Configuration.cs
> Controllers
> Controllers > UserController.cs
> Controllers > ClientController.cs etc etc
> Helpers
> Helpers > HtmlHelpers.cs
> ViewModels
> ViewModels > UserViewModel.cs
> ViewModels > ClientViewModel.cs etc etc

AppName (the ASP.NET MVC website project, no compiled code, Images/Css/JavaScripts etc... references AppName.Web only)
> Content
> Content > Images
> Content > Styles
> Scripts
> Views
```

Comment: You should be able to access HttpContext just fine from your service library just by adding the System.Web assembly reference to the project.  It will all resolve properly during runtime.  And, where did you hear that you can't use HttpContext-based logic in your services (which I assume is just a class library)?

Comment: Can't you access that from the controller before calling the service?  Or are you expecting to call directly into the service from the client?

Comment: Hey, thanks for quick comments... Jeremy: I know I can add System.Web to my Core library but I don't feel that should be dependant on things like HttpContext. Especially after reading questions like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164827/should-service-layer-have-access-to-httpcontext

Comment: mperrenoud03: Sure I can do things in the controller before hitting the service, but I'm trying to keep controllers thin without business logic from what I have read in the who skinny controller debate!! but if I have to do it there I will, just wanted a few opinions :)

Comment: @user1259167: Yes the article makes sense if you intend to slap a different face on it.  But if you use language like **can't**....well I'll just hafta prove ya wrong  :)  The key, though, is that you aren't relegated to keeping that stuff in your web app, per se. Any class library can have access to the HttpContext...how you engineer it is all you.

Comment: be aware that the HttpContext.Current.Application is only one for the whole application pool (shared between multiple sessions). If you want to store user specific data then is better to use session or cookies.

Answer (score 1):

If your service is instantiated from within your MVC app you could consider creating an interface+wrapper class and pass the instance to your service.  Something like this:

```
interface IContext
{
    int? ClientID { get; }
}

class ContextWrapper : IContext
{
    private IHttpContext Context { get; set; }

    public ContextWrapper (IHttpContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    int? ClientID 
    {
        get 
        {
             return Context.Current.Application["ClientId"] != null
                    ? (int?)HttpContext.Current.Application["ClientId"]
                    : null;
        }
    }
}

class YourService
{
    public YourService(IContext context)
    {
        // store the reference and use in your methods as needed
    }
}
```

This allows you to not take a direct dependency on System.Web from your service class.  It also sets you up nicely to unit test this as it uses IoC and can easily be hooked up for DI with constructor injection.

Comment: This is how I do it and its another point for Dependency Injection when you have many services that need it.

Comment: I do like the look of this, and going to aim to implement something along these lines. I'm aware of the benefits of IoC etc, but only just beginning to get my head around it but making progress!! short term though I also like Andrew Cooper's helper method :) thanks!!

Comment: IoC can take some time to wrap your head around.  A word of advice...the more you can pass objects in via constructors rather than new-ing up inline, the happier you will be come time to move to to a full IoC/DI solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a helper method something like this:

```
public static TResult GetFromCacheOrSource<TResult>(string cacheIndex, Func<TResult> sourceMethod)
{
    TResult result = HttpContext.Current.Application[cacheIndex] as TResult;

    if (result == null)
    {
        // If there's no value in the cache go to the source
        result = sourceMethod();
    }     
    return result;
}
```

In your controller you can then do something like this:

```
int? clientId = Helper.GetFromCacheOrSource<int?>("ClientId", () => clientService.GetClientIdFromHostname(hostname));
```

Comment: I do like this approach, and going to give this a go now. Nice and simple :)

Comment: +1 this looks like a good halfway house solution that works within the context of the mvc app without bloating the controller. nice